# sp_xml_preparedocument fails to return in openquery statement? (The metadata could not be determined)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Need to call Sp in open query.

Sample Sp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testsp
AS
DECLARE @idoc int,@doc varchar(1000)=
    '<OutLookContact>
         <Contact FirstName="Asif" LastName="Ghafoor" EmailAddress1="asifghafoor@my.web.pk" />
         <Contact FirstName="Rameez" LastName="Ali" EmailAddress1="rameezali@my.web.pk" />
     </OutLookContact>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/OutLookContact/Contact',1)
WITH 
(
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    EmailAddress1 varchar(50)
)
```

Now when executing

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( linkserver,'Exec testsp' )
```

But it returns error

> **Error Message:** Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 The metadata could not be
>   determined because every code path results in an error; see previous
>   errors for some of these. Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure
>   sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 Could not find stored procedure
>   'testsp'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must specify Database name and schema name in `exec`

   ```
   SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( linkserver,'Exec [Database].dbo.testsp' )
   ```

   But you'll get an error:

> Msg 11520, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set,
>   Line 1 The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC
>   sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc' in procedure 'testsp'
>   invokes an extended stored procedure.

2. You need a [workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2012/07/12/workaround-sql-server-2012-openrowset-on-msdb-dbo-sp-help-job-throws-error.aspx) - wrap you SP to new SP with result set:

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE testsp2
   AS

   EXEC testsp
   WITH RESULT SETS
   (
       (
           FirstName nvarchar(max),
           LastName nvarchar(max),
           EmailAddress1  nvarchar(max)
       )
   );
   ```

   And call it:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( linkserver,'Exec [Database].dbo.testsp2'
   ```

   Or modify your first SP in such way.

Comment: Thanks.. This is what i need.

Comment: Need your help again [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651662/length-error-when-using-dynamic-sql-statement-in-openquery)

Comment: @Ragul you can ask new question :)

Comment: I already did check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651662/length-error-when-using-dynamic-sql-statement-in-openquery

Comment: @Ragul oh, I see. I'll check it later, and try to help